# jquery autocomplete is undefined

Tags: jquery, html, django, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement an autocomplete search input in Django using jquery.

I have seen quite a few similar questions on this issue, but nothing solved my specific case.

In my `base.html` class I have a `head` that looks like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then in my `home.html` class, which extends `base.html` I have the following in `head`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then in the `<body>` of my `home.html` file I have:

```html
<input name="object-search"class="form-control "id="search">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $("#search").autocomplete({
          source: "/api/",
          minLength: 1,
        });
    });

</script>
```

In my `home.html` the order looks like this:
[image]

When going to `home.html` I get the following error:
[image]

Comment: Have you also attached `jQuery` library?

Comment: Forgive my javascript ignorance, but isn't that what this line is: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: Damn, sorry my bad, I missed it somehow. But can you check if it's for sure attached on your `home.html` and its above the attaching `jquery.ui`?

Comment: I edited it to show a screenshot of `home.html` from browser console

Comment: @cph2117 nothing looks suspicious here. could you create a fiddle and replicate this ?

Comment: @Deep I was able to get it to work on a standalone basis...So could it be an issue with implementing in Django?

Answer (score 0):

Very dumb error. I had an extra `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`
 at the bottom of my `base.html` file that must've been overriding/nullifying the other import.